# How to I add flowJS type to custom web component?

Tags: javascript, web-component, flowtype, custom-component

I have a custom component(not React) on my page, and flow thinks that it's a React Component and tries to resolve it with React. See the below picture.

[image]

Is there any way to tell flow that this is a custom web component and stop it from throwing type error?

For now, there is a workaround to tell flow that this is something to do with Snabbdom. Well actually below the line(#1) is intended for Babel but Flow is smart enough to interpret that and resolve.

```
// @jsx snabbdom.createElement

import snabbdom from 'snabbdom-renderer'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

I am just wondering if there is any concrete fix for this?